# How do I stop Pulseaudio using huge amounts of memory?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

My install of Ubuntu Studio 17.04 seems to have several issues with audio

one of them being Pulseaudio its appears to be using a vast amount of memory on my 16GB machine currently at 2.85GB of memory being used I have seen it over 3GB

Please can you explain the solution in easy to understand steps I'm still learning Linux.

It also sounds like its garbled at times too I need smooth audio for DJ production work.

Comment: Thanks all the same But I no longer use Linux. I'm back on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that this is real memory consumption and not virtual-only? According to https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/MemoryConsumption/, it reserves 64 MB per client on virtual memory, but that should actually be "fine" and not result in OOM situations. On my 18.04 ubuntu, top shows e.g.

```
%Cpu(s):  4,1 us,  1,5 sy,  0,0 ni, 93,2 id,  1,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem : 16135328 total,  1088888 free,  8108764 used,  6937676 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  1003516 total,   961276 free,    42240 used.  6562996 avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                   
[...]                                                                                
20428 delf       9 -11 2464944  13808  10264 S   4,6  0,1   3:05.72 pulseaudio
```

So ~2,5 gig on virtual memory, while actually %-memory consumed measured with ps shows:

```
% ps -o pid,%mem,command ax | grep pulseaudio
 1811  0.0 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no
 7363  0.0 grep pulseaudio
20428  0.0 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog
```

So maybe everything is just fine..? :)

Comment: Thanks delf! So the 0.1 `%MEM` from `top` or `ps` output is the actual percentage of memory consumption from the total, which is what really matters, right?

Comment: yes, it should be :)

Answer (score 0):

As I answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1384477/1557471), if you want to **reduce the virtual memory size** of pulseaudio:

Find your pulseaudio daemon config (most likely `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`) and uncomment and change the setting `enable-shm` as such:

```
enable-shm = no
```

Then reboot your machine, or restart pulseaudio with

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

This will not give you any real memory savings and will cause imperceptible performance overhead, but the virtual memory usage will go down and you will gain peace of mind!

Answer (score 0):

Pulseaudio is known to have high RAM (physical memory) usage in some cases.

Try disabling PulseAudio’s timer-based scheduling by adding `tsched=0` to the end of the `load-module module-udev-detect` line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

---

Alternatively, reduce the number of channels that PulseAudio uses. You can do this by editing the `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` file and changing the `default-fragments` and `default-fragment-size-msec` values.