# How do I stop Pulseaudio using huge amounts of VIRTUAL memory?

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, resource-limiting

How do I stop Pulseaudio using huge amounts VIRTUAL of memory?

```
USER         PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
jabowery 2421222  0.6  0.0 62272820 61344 ?      Sl   17:08   0:32 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/wrapper-2.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/panel/plugins/libpulseaudio-plugin.so 9 12582919 pulseaudio PulseAudio Plugin Adjust the audio volume of the PulseAudio sound system
```

Note the significant difference(s) between this question and a prior question:

[How do I stop Pulseaudio using huge amounts of memory?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988352/how-do-i-stop-pulseaudio-using-huge-amounts-of-memory)

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but why block the assignment of virtual memory? This is generally a value that is maximally available to the service if required (until it asks for more). It does not mean that is how much memory is actually being consumed in the RAM or swap ...

Comment: Why report something that is a resource limit rather than something that is actually a resource?  There are other commands to obtain resource limits.  The expected resource use for virtual memory would be something like swap usage.

Answer (score 0):

Find your pulseaudio daemon config (most likely `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`) and uncomment and change the setting `enable-shm` as such:

```
enable-shm = no
```

Then reboot your machine, or restart pulseaudio with

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

This will not give you any real memory savings and will cause imperceptible performance overhead, but the virtual memory usage will go down and you will gain peace of mind!